# Store username and password on wildfly and fetch with java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly, wildfly-18

I need to store ldap username and password in wildfly.
I did as follow but my manager said is not safe how I did:

```
String ldapCredentials = System.getProperty("ldap.user");
    byte[] credDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ldapCredentials == null ? "" : ldapCredentials);
    String credentials = new String(credDecoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String[] ldapDecoded = credentials.split(",");
    ldapSearchUser = ldapDecoded[0];
    ldapSearchPassword = ldapDecoded[1];
```

in the standalone:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="ldap.user" value="randomvaluebase64"/>
</system-properties>
```

He told me I need to use the security default of wildfly, I found a lot of things about it but i wasn't able to find how to fetch in java than, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**The original answer I provided only applies to WildFly 23 or newer. I'll leave it below the correct answer for reference.**

You'll want to use a [credential store](https://docs.wildfly.org/18/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#keystorecredentialstore), which encrypts the contents with a Java KeyStore. The linked documentation goes into details, but [this example class](https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/blob/1.x/credential-store/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/examples/CredentialStoreExample.java) shows how you can retrieve the contents of the credential store.

To secure the credential store password itself, you have a few options:

- Read the password from the output of a shell command ([source code](https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/2.x/credential/source/impl/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/credential/source/impl/CommandCredentialSource.java)). **This is the only method I recommend, since the password cannot be stored in the configuration file.** For example, this CLI command would create the credential store using an environment variable as password:

```bash
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/credential-store=cs:add(location=credstore.cs,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir,\
credential-reference={type=command,clear-text="echo $SECURE_ENV_VAR"},create=true)
```

- Store the password in plain text. Given the constraints, this isn't a realistic option.
- Using Elytron Tool, you can create a credential store with a hashed-and-salted password. However, this is a purely compatibility feature, and the algorithm used (`PBEwithMD5andDES`) is now brute-forceable, so I **don't recommend** it, and won't include instructions on how to do so.

If you're able to upgrade to WildFly 23 or newer, you'll have access to a more secure option, as defined below.

---

- [Credential store documentation for WildFly 28](https://docs.wildfly.org/28/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#CredentialStore)
- [Example class for WildFly 28](https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/blob/main/credential-store/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/examples/CredentialStoreExample.java)

As for adding the LDAP credentials (and securing the password for the credential store itself), [this blog post](https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/wildfly-encrypted-expressions/) explains how to use them with encrypted expressions. This allows you to store an encrypted copy of the credential store's password in the server configuration.

*Note: although it may seem like you can use an encrypted expression directly to store the LDAP credentials, it will not be resolved in a non-secure context, and likely won't work in the Java class.*

Comment: can I do the same with wildfly18? I need to store my username and password

Comment: Sorry, the instructions I originally provided only apply to WildFly 23 and up. I've corrected it for WildFly 18.

Comment: do you know how can i fetch the password in spring once you saved in the credential store